# xcode changing view controllers issues

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have been developing an iPhone app and have come across a few issues. I do not have a storyboard in my app and have nothing in my xibs. I have initialised and set everything up through code. When I go to the GameViewController from my main viewcontroller everything is fine, however when I come back through my back button I get this issue:

> Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged .

When I re-arrive to the main view controller, there are little changes such as the view changing before its supposed to. Here is the code for the button on my

```
GameViewController *game = [[GameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:Nil];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    [self presentViewController:game animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Here is the code for the back button:

```
ViewController *home = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
[self presentViewController:home animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

If anyone can help me to see what I am doing wrong that would be great.

Comment: Doesn't the back button remove your view automatically? Why would you handle it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not present `home` view controller from `self` because it is already dismissed. You should change

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
[self presentViewController:home animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

to

```
UIViewController *parentViewController = self.presentingViewController;
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^
 {
     [parentViewController presentViewController:home animated:NO completion:nil];
 }];
```

Comment: Now I get an error that says: Warning: Attempt to present <ViewController: 0x15dc1960> on <ViewController: 0x15e73670> while a presentation is in progress! The main menu also isn't working once it has loaded.

Comment: Now it is very glitchy so that when I pressed my button upon re-arrival, all sorts is happening but your code did work for my issue so thanks.

Comment: Can I just ask you one more question? Is there any need to dismiss the parentViewController?

Comment: No, you do not need to dismiss parentViewController. But generally it depends on what GUI logic you want to have.

Comment: You can open new question if you need some help with another issue.